# MS Access RecordSource selection error

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2016

I am new to Access and have a form that displays a list of employees that is fetched from a query. It is a continuous list and I have a way to filter by employee type. I wanted to isolate the new record in the continuous form, so I added a button that changes `DataEntry = True`, however, when changing `DataEntry = False`, I ran into issues with the filtering working, and they appeared to stem around the `RecordSource`.

The filtering is done using a `combobox` that calls a simple 'Requery' 'AfterUpdate()', and the query itself gets the values as criteria from the `combobox` selection.

In the button to change to `DataEntry = False`, I have been trying to assign the `RecordSource` as well. Initially, it seemed to work great, but then Access crashed and now I am getting error `3701` once the button is pressed.

I have tried various different syntax to try to set the `RecordSource`.

`Me.RecordSource = "qryName"`
`Form.RecordSource = "qryName`
`Forms!frmName.RecordSource = "qryName`

and all of the above with `"SELECT * FROM [qryName]"` instead of a simple string.

Each gives me a 3701 error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you need to use the query as your recordsource?   Is your query joining multiple tables, or are you just using the query to filter the recordset?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds overly complicated. Just set the *Filter* property of the form - you can use the combobox to do that:

```
Me.Filter = "EmployeeType = '" & Me!ComboSelectedType.Value "'"
Me.FilterOn = True
```

or, if the value is numeric:

```
Me.Filter = "EmployeeType = " & Me!ComboSelectedType.Value ""
Me.FilterOn = True
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize I could do this with queries that pulled from multiple tables, but after some work, it achieved exactly what I was looking for.